# Antd V3. Table component. How to calculate sum of column values

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need your help to calculate the sum of column values using Ant Design Table component.

Here is an example of table:
[Example][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYBRO.png

Here is my code for columns and rows:

```js
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Jon',
    apple: 1,
    orange: 1,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Ron',
    apple: 0,
    orange: 3,
  },
];

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Apple',
    dataIndex: 'apple',
    key: 'apple',
  },
  {
    title: 'Orange',
    dataIndex: 'orange',
    key: 'orange',
  },
];

<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
```

I know that it's easy to do in version 4 of Antd, but I'm unable to migrate right now.

How can I count the sum of each columns to push it for the new row?

Comment: You can use `Array.reduce()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data.concat(
      (() => {
        let apple = 0;
        let orange = 0;
        for (let row of data) {
          apple += row["apple"];
          orange += row["orange"];
        }
        return { key: "total", name: "Total (by Column)", apple, orange };
      })()
    )}
  />
```